# Attribute-based cryptography

Tags: implementation, abe

I am trying to create a social network, in which I want to use attribute-based cryptography. One professor told me it is possible to do it only in J2EE, but he can barely code! Some friends of mine suggested using .NET.

I know through research that both are feasible, but since it is going to be a web-based application I was wondering if it would be possible to do it in PHP. Does anyone know? I can't find any material regarding this.

Is it difficult to implement algorithms in PHP? Can I implement AES or other symmetric algorithms in PHP? OR should I just stick to .NET?

Comment: Your question boils down to what language to use, if certain languages are better than others for implementing ABE, etc. This isn't really on topic here and is primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

If you need something that already exists, have a look at the advanced Crypto software collection and specifically [cpabe](http://hms.isi.jhu.edu/acsc/cpabe/) — which implements ciphertext-policy attribute-based encryption scheme that uses C and PBC library for pairings.

Comment: In my readings, I have found MIRACL and the PBC you mentioned used in ABE. But it still brings me back to how I can use it...